# Constructor a parameter in a method call

Tags: java, methods, constructor

What is this type of passing constructor to a method called in Java
(the Class_name is an internal class)?

```
method_name(new Class_name(arguments));
```

How can we pass constructor without having an instance of the object?

Comment: You're not passing a constructor.  You're passing a new instance of `Class_name`.

Comment: Yes, `Class_name` is a constructor, but take note of the [**new** keyword](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html). "The *new* operator instantiates a class by allocating memory for a new object and returning a reference to that memory. The *new* operator also invokes the object constructor." You are therefore passing an instance of `Class_name` to `method_name`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, actually `new Class_name(arguments)` *will* create a new instance of the class. A construction might be useful - it is more concise than

```
Class_name instance = new Class_name(arguments);
method_name(instance);
```

but you would not be able to access `instance` later on.

Answer (score 1):

As has been said, you are passing a new object.

If you want to pass just the information about this class, then your method would need to take a [Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor%28java.lang.Class...%29) an an argument, for example...

```
public void method_name(Class clz) { ... do something... )
```

You would call it like this...

```
method_name( Class_name.class);
```

The other thing doing literally what you wanted would be to give the Constructor, which you can get, for example, by...

```
Constructor const = Class_name.class.getConstructor( ArgumentType.class, AnotherArgumentType.class, ...);
```

for example...

```
Constructor const = Class_name.class.getConstructor( String.class);
```

...if your constructor took one `String` argument.

And then call your method...

```
public void method_name(Constructor constructor) { ... do something... )
```

... with...

```
method_name( const );
```

The last way is very specific and I doubt that it's actually what you NEED, no matter what you think you might need.

Answer (score 0):

new creates a object and this is passed to the function. You are not passing class you are passing "new" of that class which will create a object

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing a constructor, an instance :

When you do :

```
MyClass myClass = new Myclass();
method_name(myClass);
```

You have an instance of `MyClass` into `myClass`. then you call `method_name` with `myClass` as an argument

So this can be shortened as :

```
method_name(new Myclass());
```

Answer (score 0):

These types of use cases are very common for **Decorator design pattern**, where you do not require the intermediate objects.

Example:

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader(filename);
LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(fr);
```

or

```
LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(filename));
```

Take a look at I/O classes from nio framework for more understanding on these types of use cases.